# C Ways To Pass Function As Argument To Function

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I've notices that there seem to be different ways to pass a function as a parameter to another function.  The prototypes are:

```
void foo1(double f(double));
```

and

```
void foo2(double (*f)(double));
```

Is there a difference between the two?  Are they implemented in the same way?  Are there any other ways to pass functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second is arguably the 'proper' way to write it.  It says that the argument to `foo1()` is a pointer to a function.  The first says that the argument is a function, but you can't pass functions as functions per se, so the compiler treats it as a pointer to function.  So, in practice, they are equivalent — in this context.  But, in other contexts, you would not be able to use the `double f(double);` notation to declare a pointer to function.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)
>
> ¶8 A declaration of a parameter as "function returning *type*" shall be adjusted to "pointer to
>   function returning *type*", as in 6.3.2.1.

#### Subsidiary question and answer

> Could you please give an example where `double f(double);` wouldn't work?

```
#include <math.h>

double (*pointer)(double) = sin;
double function(double);   // This declares the existence of 'function()'
```

This is at file scope; it could also be in a block of code, such as inside a function.  The pointer to function notation works as you intend.  The plain function simply declares a function — not variable that holds a pointer to function.

The only places where the notations are (loosely) equivalent is inside a function argument list:

Declarations:

```
double integrate(double lo, double hi, double (*function)(double));
double differentiate(double lo, double hi, double function(double));
```

Definitions:

```
double integrate(double lo, double hi, double (*function)(double))
{
    ...
}

double differentiate(double lo, double hi, double function(double))
{
    ...
}
```

The function or function pointer parameters could be used interchangeably in these declarations and definitions, but only in the parameter list — not in the body of the function.

Because the explicit 'pointer to function' notation works everywhere and the other notation only works in a very limited set of places, you should generally use the explicit 'pointer to function' notation, even though it is a little more verbose.

Comment: Could you please give an example where `double f(double);` wouldn't work?

Comment: @user968243: Just a straightforward pointer definition, `double f(double) = my_double_func;` wouldn't work, but `double (*f)(double) = my_double_func;` would.

Comment: Is there any sort of general consensus as to which syntax should be preferred?  The first one seems more readable, but slightly misleading, while the second is more cumbersome to write yet clearly reflects what's going on.

Comment: Use the pointer to function (second) notation.  As you say, it is explicit and works correctly everywhere whereas the first notation can only be used in function argument lists.

Answer (score 4):

Both methods declare the same parameter type. There's no difference between the two whatsoever. A parameter of function type is implicitly adjusted to pointer-to-function type, meaning that the first declaration is interpreted by the compiler as equivalent to the second one. It is a matter of personal preference, which one you want to use in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to pass function as argument to function

```
typedef void (*functiontype)();
```

Declaring a function

```
void dosomething() { }

functiontype func = &dosomething;
func();
```

these are library that can help with turning function pointers into nice readable types. The boost function library is great and is well worth the effort!

```
boost::function<int (char a)> functiontype2;
```

Example:

```
for ( int ctr = 0 ; ctr < 5 ; ctr++ ) {
  print(ctr);
}

void func ( void (*f)(int) ) {
  for ( int ctr = 0 ; ctr < 5 ; ctr++ ) {
    (*f)(ctr);
  }
}
```